# ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

multilabel-indicator is not supported is the error message I get, when trying to run:
can you give me any solution or hint.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred), annot = True)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ee6823d584e9> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred), annot = True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight, normalize)
    317     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    318     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
--> 319         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)
    320 
    321     if labels is None:

ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

Comment: according to the error the target variable is in multilabel-indicator type(which means where each sample can belong to multiple classes or categories simultaneously ie multiple labels) and the confusion matrix doesn't support this type

Answer (score 0):

Your y_data needs to be flat and categorical (binary or multiclass), i.e. of the forms

```
    from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
    >>> type_of_target([1.0, 2.0])
    'binary'
    >>> type_of_target([1, 0, 2])
    'multiclass'
    >>> type_of_target([1.0, 0.0, 3.0])
    'multiclass'
    >>> type_of_target(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    'multiclass'
```

Depending how your y_pred looks like you need to categorize it to fit the above patterns, e.g. not one-hot encoded.

Likely you have to post-process your model outputs first in the following way

```
y_pred = outputs.argmax(axis=1)
```